# Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have read the Laravel's documentation. It is very brief and compressed. How should I implement the following SQL query:

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE `column1` = 5 AND `column2`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with query builder:

```
$results = DB::table('table')->where('column1','=',5)->where('column2','=',5)->get('title');
```

With eloquent you should have models defined and could use it like:

```
$users = User::where('column1','=',5)->where('column2','=',5)->get('title')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
$users = User::where('column1', 5)->where('column2', 4)->get()->fetch('title')->all();
```